# C# classes for SelectionKey, SelectableChannel and Selector in Java?

Tags: c#, java, .net

What are C# classes for SelectionKey, SelectableChannel and Selector in Java? Are there any direct translations of those classes or what are the next best things?

Edit:
As Marc Gravell pointed out, it's for a multiplexer for IO operations (network).

Comment: Telling us what their intent is would save some folks (who know .net but not java) some time...

Comment: ah, so its a multiplexer for IO operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any classes directly corresponding to the java.nio model in .NET. Asynchronous IO is typically performed using a `BeginRead`/`EndRead` (etc) approach. There's also the event-based asynchonous model used by classes like `WebClient`. Additionally in .NET 4 with the Task Parallel Library you can use task-based asynchrony, which can also take advantage of the `Begin`/`End` pattern.

You can read more about asynchronous IO in .NET [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx).

Note that C# 5 will introduce asynchronous methods, which will make a lot of this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx#S5) which shows an example of what I think you are trying to achieve in C#. It shows how to use [Socket.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx) to achieve Multiplexed I/O